# Format cmd.exe path output

Tags: shell, cmd

How would I pretty print the output from the `cmd.exe` shell command `path` so that each element is printed on a new line? I guess I would have to pipe it through some text munger that adds a `newline` wherever it finds the `;` character, but being a noob, I have no idea how to do this.

Also, I think I would have to take care of the macros like `%HOME%` differently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found this as an option worth noting:

```
 echo %path:;=&echo.%
```